# Google geolocation api returns server location where the app is deployed

Tags: google-api, google-geolocation

Apologies if this is weird question, but I've been trying to resolve this for a long time and I can't figure out and am little frustrated.

I'm developing a webapp and need to use Google geolocation API (I'm aware of HTML5 geolocation api but it's not for my use case). when developing locally the api returns lat/long with big accuracy number. that's because I set `considerIp` to true. which is completely fine, at least I can detect the city.

That being said, when I deploy my app to real servers and test it via phone, it returns east coast locations!! I'm sure api can't figure out and falls back to ip detection.

So what is the use of geolocation api? is it not for client side development? Certainly I can't include `cellTowers` or `wifiAccessPoints` in the request body since it's not possible to detect those on client. and documentation on this api is poor.

I'm trying to accomplish user approximate location for better app experience. Is this achievable via google geolocation api?

Many thanks.

PS. I know about other geolocation services that uses IP lookup, maybe they will be my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to this [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview), please make sure your client is invoking the HTTP GET request to the `www.googleapis.com` API endpoint, and not the server. That should help the API backend detect your client's public IP address correctly for the `considerIp` configuration.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to that api. According to docs it accepts POST requests only. I've already tried that but still the same. basically I've tried both, client doing the api call and also requesting my backend to do the api call :(